# Vue dynamic html form from Django

Tags: django-forms, vue.js, vuejs2

i have `FormView` in Django and i want display this form in Modal. So i make Vue component and on create i call this:

```
created: function(){
    let self = this;
    $.get(window.profileUrls.registration, function (data){  
        $('#registerModal').replaceWith(data);       
        self.$forceUpdate();
    });
}
```

Django returns HTML with form and i replace default empty modal with this HTML. But force update don't reinitialize `v-model` and other bindings and vue don't update component data.

Is it some way to reinitialize component manually after GET request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Async-Components

Solution i am currently using:

```
Vue.component('async-example', function (resolve, reject) {
  get('backendurl', function (data) {
    // Pass the component definition to the resolve callback
    resolve({
      template: data
    })
  });
})
```